# IDE Plugin for XMLDoc

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, xml-documentation

there is an IDE Plugin out there (I think it was **not** free) which assists in writing XMLDocumention inside the IDE. I tried to search for it, but I cannot find it anymore. Anybody knows it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [`Documentation Insight`](http://www.devjet.net/) from DevJet

[image]

Comment: @alex: RRUZ never said it was free, and the OP said they were aware what they were looking for was not free.

Comment: Mis-read the question ... Need to get some sleep sometimes :)