# XMLDoc Delphi source code documentation generation

Tags: delphi, documentation-generation

I assume that XML and [Delphi Documentation Guidelines](http://www.devjet.net/downloads/Delphi-Documentation-Guidelines.pdf) are becoming the de-facto standard for source-code documenting comments. That is good. The bad thing is that I cannot find any Delphi documentation generator (free or commercial) that fully supports these standards (for example Doc-O-Matic Express does not support <list> tags).

The question is: what XML documentation standards and Delphi source code XMLDoc documentation generators are ready to use now?

Comment: It's good apart from the bit where humans have to read and write XML!

Comment: @David: No, you quickly get accustomed to writing XML. It is something like writing Pascal :)

Comment: @Serg I have never got accustomed to writing XML. I suppose it is going to be easier for programmers to *get* it than for non-programmers. Personally I'm a huge fan of YAML.

Comment: IMHO XML is for human quick inspection only. Not for writing. It is too verbose and hampers reading too much.  But a simple editor can go a long way

Comment: @Macro: I am talking about XMLDoc-style in-source documenting comments. I like to write them, and I don't want to use any WYSIWYG XML editor for it. I still think that currently Doc-O-Matic is the best choice to generate Delphi source code documentation, though I must say that my commitment to Doc-O-Matic "has cooled significantly" ;)

Comment: @Serg: Other than List tag support, doc-o-matic does what you want?

Comment: @Warren: That depends on what you want. Sure doc-o-matic is the best documentation generator for Delphi sources, and you can use it, taking into account the list of supported XML tags (if you use XMLDoc style)

Answer (score 4):

*(You are asking two questions. That's probably why you are getting no answers.)*

On the tools front, take a look at these previously asked questions:

- [IDE Plugin for XMLDoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713349/ide-plugin-for-xmldoc)
- [Code documentation for delphi similar to javadoc or c# xml doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236047/code-documentation-for-delphi-similar-to-javadoc-or-c-xml-doc)

Comment: -1. The question is single, and the above is not an answer to it.

Comment: Well, your phrasing is somewhat strange. I thought you were asking for XML documentation standards and delphi source code XMLDoc generators. In the second link I provided you can find a tool for DelphiCodeToDoc which may or may not help you. Anyways, you are welcome.

Comment: DelphiCodeToDoc does not support XML at all.

Comment: @Serg: It's open source. How hard would it be to add that to it? Not very hard, I bet.

Answer (score 0):

I would check these products:

- [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/)
- [NDoc 3](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ndoc3/) (but maybe it requires access to .Net assemblies - then it will not work)